# How to use a a library module in a front-end external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Situation:

I have a server side running with express.js and there I get data from SQL database. I would like to show this data to the client side, by sending it to the client.

In the front-end, I need to take this data and make it into a chart. It is possible to do it with the  tag in the HTML and include the *Plotly* library, which I want to use. However, I would like this operation to be done in a separate file, an external JS script for client. This avoids hard-to-read code in the *HTML*.

The problem is, how can I import *Plotly* to the external front-end file and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your need correctly :
One simple option would be to include both of your script in your html related document with the one required by the second one first :

```html
...
<script src="path script 1" />
<script src="path script 2 depending on script 1" />
```

so in your case using CDN :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="path of your script where you use ploty"></script>
```

PS:
Also just a proposition but did you thing about importing Ploty in your js backend and use it in your front-end ? or with post/get or with socket ?

Comment: Oh, that worked just the way I wanted, thank You. I'm quite new to this, just got thrown into a project I have to to.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply load it from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/plotly.js/1.33.1) :) That's what CDNs are here for

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/1.33.1/plotly-basic.min.js">
```